# Get src attribute of and img and do an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have alot of images in my table rows. Whatever image is clicked, I want to display its src in an alert box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Register click events */
    $(".tableImages").click(function(){
        imageClickEvent().call(this);
    });


});


function imageClickEvent()
{

    if($(this).is("img"))
    {
        alert("YES"); //nothing happens
    }

}
```

Comment: Look in your console. `imageClickEvent().call(this);` probably give you an error because `undefined` does not have a method named `.call`.

Comment: oh yes it does!. what does that mean btw?

Comment: `imageClickEvent()` executes the function immediately, and your function returns nothing. Then you try `.call` on the "nothing" (undefined) which is an error.

Comment: I believe you want `imageClickEvent.call(this);` or just `$(".tableImages").click(imageClickEvent)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="http://img.kooora.com/?i=ali.18%2f2016%2f2%2f5%2f1%2f01_05203041_a54046_2675418a.jpg&z=320|240&c=65|0|1333|1000&h=137" class="btnimg" />

<script>


$(document).on('click' , '.btnimg', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('src')) ; 
});

</script>
```

in brief you need to have dummy class and you will assign click event based on that class, then it will be easy to get any attribute for the current event soource using $(this) pointer, hopefully helpful, this work in Jquery

Comment: Instead of doing `$(document).on('click' , '.btnimg',`, you should do `$(".btnimg").on("click",` instead because the way you are doing will attach the listener to every newly created `img.btnimg` (unless this is your intention.)

Comment: yes, that what I mean, you may be need to add other image from js, so this will allow him to have the event on the new image

Comment: thanks guys. Yes i might need to add other images dynamically

Comment: @AlaaAbuzaghleh Ah ok :)

Comment: I believe it would be more helpful to explain what's wrong with the OP's code and just fix it. You are introducing event delegation without explaining how it works and when it's useful.

Comment: Is it right to say the on is for dynamically attaching the events whereas what i did is a one time binding?

Comment: @RStyle: Technically no. `.on` also performs the binding only once. The difference is that when you pass a selector as second argument, the event handler will only fire if the event target matches the selector.